# Pivot tables with actual entries

Tags: google-sheets

I have a form that populates a spreadsheet with data pairs in the form of Manufacturer-Category, like this:

```
Mfr Category
A   Servers
A   Workstations
B   Components
C   Workstations
D   Networking
E   Workstations
F   Other
G   Components
```

I would like to build a pivot table-like listing with Category entries as the column headings but with a list of Manufacturers under each:

```
Servers Workstations Components Networking Other
A       A            B          D          F
        C            G
        E
```

Categories may be added down the road, so I would like them to be detected automatically like in a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(A1:B8," select max(A) group by A pivot B"),,5000))," ")))
```

You cannot order the titles though.

Comment: if there are spaces in the category name, it will put them as entries.  I see the route you're taking though, this may be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Since my data contains spaces, using anonymous's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46305022/4468423) as a basis, I came up with the following solution:

1. Use an intermediate sheet `Sheet2` for referencing if spaces exist in the data. Cell A1 contains the formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet1'!A:B," ","_"))
```

2. On a third sheet `Sheet3`, enter the following in cell A1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(Sheet2!$A$1:$B$1000,"select max(A) group by A pivot B",1),,5000))," ")),"_"," "))
```

Explaining what each formula does in sequence:

`QUERY(Sheet2!$A$1:$B$1000,"select max(A) group by A pivot B",1)` does a Google Visualization API lookup to produce the following result:

```
Components Networking Other Servers Workstations

                            A       A
B
                                    C
           D            
                                    E
                      F     
G
```

It's starting to look like a pivot table, but there are unnecessary gaps between elements of each column.

`QUERY( ... ,,5000)` is a straight up hack.  It takes the previous query result and concatenates all the columns and their entries into a single row of cells.  A pipe has been added below to denote a new cell in the row.  Note the spaces between entries.

`Components   B     G   |Networking     D       |Other       F  |Servers  A         |Workstations  A  C  E`

`TRANSPOSE( ... )` takes this row result and turns it into a column.

```
Components   B     G
Networking     D   
Other       F 
Servers  A      
Workstations  A  C  E
```

`SPLIT( ... ," ")` separates text into neat columns.  Multiple space characters are ignored.  Note: this and following functions will not display without being surrounded by `ARRAYFORMULA()`.

```
Components   B G   
Networking   D      
Other        F      
Servers      A      
Workstations A C E
```

`TRANSPOSE( ... )` puts everything back into columns:

```
Components Networking Other Servers Workstations
B          D          F     A       A
G                                   C
                                    E
```

Finally, we strip out the underscores and replace with spaces using `SUBSTITUTE( ... ,"_"," ")` and surround everything with `ARRAYFORMULA()` so it will display.

Comment: Although you've explained a lot (good job at that), You've only substituted spaces with `_` and undid it later. Does this warrant an another solution? Considering the fact that your original Question or the included sample in your question never had spaces in categories, I don't think this Question warrants an another answer. There will always be slight modifications to the answers provided to suit your own data style ( as we don't have full access to all your data), but,IMO that doesn't necessitate an another answer, which only satisfies another criteria, not mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: at the time i posted, your answer was removed.